# How to change the alignment of a view without changing its width or height

Tags: swift, swiftui, alignment, modifier

I'm trying to adjust the alignment of a `Text` view in SwiftUI. Though I don't want to adjust its width or height using the `.frame` modifier. I'm looking for something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
            .frame(alignment: .leading) // builds and runs, yet doesn't change alignment
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: It is the parent view of your text that should decide where to put it (or how to align it). That said, the .frame modifier does not change the width of the text itself. It embeds it in a container which can then decide how to align your text. Please show us the context of where your text resides in. Or explain why you don’t want to embed your text in a frame that lays out your text according to your alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.frame(alignment: .leading)` is leading within *own* frame, so it is aligned but frame is tight to content by default, and centerred within parent container by default, so you don't see any changes.

To get what you try to achieve (as I assume) it should be

```
Text("Hello World!") // text view
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // alignment view
```

Comment: Not sure how this is the accepted solution when the question asks how to set the alignment WITHOUT changing the frame. This will change the frame. e.g. in an HStack with maxWidth of 600, this will cause the Text to fill the width of that HStack.